# Как установить компилятор C++ в Sublime Text 3 на Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sublime-text, компилятор

Возможно ли установить компилятор языка C++ в Sublime Text 3 на Ubuntu 16.04? Так,чтобы написать код, нажать кнопку и получить результат?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089548/compile-and-run-c-in-sublime-text-2-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 включает две build-системы: C++ и Make.
Файл `C++.sublime-build` выглядит так:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Для использования надо найти в меню `Tools -> Build System` и выбрать `C++`. После этого можно использовать комбинацию клавиш `Ctrl+B` для запуска билда.

Источник: [перевод аналогичного вопроса на SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196509)